# TestNG test class for a well encapsulated class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I am unit testing a class with the following structure.

```
public class Experiment {

    private final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    Experiment(Set<String> set){
        for(String str :set ){
            map.put(str,str);
        }
    }

    public String getVal(String str){
        return map.get(str);
    }

}
```

As seen my class has only one instance variable that is a HashMap. Now i want to make sure my map is correctly populated through my constructor which takes a HashSet. 
Since I can create a expected Map structure independently.
But i am stuck now because my 'map' is "private" in my class.
I dont want to expose my state variable to outside world by making it public.
Please suggest a way to Unit test my map variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could access to your map variable through `Reflection` but it's **NOT** a good practice to test your private implementation details directly. The better approach would be to *test the public API that depends on that private stuff*. In your case test whether `getVal` method returns the same value you added to the map or not. [Read more on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes).

Answer (score 1):

What I personally do is make the field package-private. And I annotate it with Guava's [`@VisibleForTesting`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html).

But that's only when I'm testing the internal state. Usually, you want to test what the public API (usually `public` and `protected` members) offer.

Answer (score 1):

If `Experiment` is meant to be a map-like object you could extend use `google/guava` and extend [`ForwardingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html). See [Forwarding Decorators](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#forwarding-decorators) in [CollectionHelpersExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained#forwarding-decorators) for details.

e.g.

```
public class Experiment extends ForwardingMap<String,String> {
    private final Map<String,String> map;

    Experiment(Set<String> set){
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(String str :set ){
            map.put(str,str);
        }
        this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> delegate() {
        return map;
    }

    public String getVal(String str){
        return map.get(str);
    }
}
```

This will make `Experiment` implement `Map` so that publicly you can call things like `get(Object)`, `containsKey(Object)`, `entrySet()`, etc. but calling any modifier methods like `put(String, String)` will throw an exception. Then you can compare `Experiment` with any other `Map` in your tests to compare the key-value entry sets.